# matlab omit sum from cellfun

Tags: matlab

HI I have the following:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) sum(cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

and I want to omit the sum and change to:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) cross(u{1},x),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

However the error I am getting:

```
??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in ==> cellcross at 4
    bres = reshape(bmat,size(grid'));    %reshape the get columns of bfield vectors in x y z format
```

reason being I don't think I am summing in the right place. I want to do sum(cross(u{1},r{1}))....sum(cross(u{1},r{n})) but the result doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Works for me. As long as `u{1}` and `r{i}` have the same size (specifically 3 element vectors) `b = cellfun(@(x) sum(cross(u{1},x)), r, 'UniformOutput',false)` should work for what you want. You are computing the cross-product of pairs of vectors (i.e. the 3-element vector), summing it and assigning it to a new cell. Omitting the sum you will get 3-element cross-products in each element of cell b.

Comment: @gevang - thanks for your reply. it's actually when I omit the sum I get the above error (the second definition of b)

Comment: What types (and sizes) are `r` and `u` exactly?

Comment: @Eitan size(u) = [1 1], size(r) = [1 81] and they are both of type cell.

Comment: u = [3 x 81] double, r = 81 [3 x 81] doubles.

Comment: I meant 1) both cases work for me (with and without the `sum`), 2) the version with the `sum` will actually do what you want, i.e. get the sums of all cross. If it is something else you want, please edit your post.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?